# Event Handler to run only when previous event handling is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling, jquery-events

Attached Event handler to callback like :

```
$("someSelector").on('click',callBackHandler);

function callBackHandler(){
   //Some code
   $.ajax({
     //Ajax call with success methods
   })
}
```

My success method is manipulating some object properties. Since ajax is involved, it will not wait for the completion and next event handling will start. How can I make sure next click event handling starts only when previous handling is done.

Cannot think of a way of using deferred manually on this because I am triggering event manually on base of some condition in for loop (Not a clean style of coding, but has no other option in particular use case).

```
$('someSelector').trigger('click');
```

Comment: You can add `flag` and toggle its value between `ajax` start and end events.  And keep a check inside `click` event for that flag's value

Comment: Can you explain  _only when previous handling is done_ ?

Comment: In the Ajax Response: $.when(put_your_function_call_in_here()).done(function(response) { ... your ajax response stuff here... });

Comment: @RayonDabre want to say next callbackHandler on event should run only when previous callbackHandler is completed

Comment: `.off/.on` will help! But better to deal with `global` flag..

Answer (score 1):

```
$("someSelector").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var urAjax = $.ajax({
        // Ajax Call here...
    });

    urAjax.always(function(response) {
        $.when( callBackHandler() ).done(function() {
            // Handle your ajax response in here!
        });
    });
});

function callBackHandler() {
    // Do Stuff 
}
```

`callBackHandler` function will fire, and when it's done, your ajax response for .always will fire directly after that.  This allows for your ajax to load while the `callBackHandler` function is running also, but doesn't fire the response until after the function is done!  Hopefully I'm understanding what you are asking for here.

You can see an example jsfiddle located here:  https://jsfiddle.net/e39oyk8q/11/

Try clicking the submit button multiple times before the AJAX request is finished, you will notice that it will loop over and over again the total amount of clicks you give it on the Submit button.  You can see this by the amount of times the Alert box pops up, and also, it adds 100 to the len (that gets outputted on the page) during each call to the `callBackHandler` function.  So, I do believe this is what you asked for.

And, ofcourse, you can still use:  `$('someSelector').trigger('click');`

**EDIT**

Another approach is to return a json object that can be used within the ajax call or wherever you need it within the click event, like so:

```
$("someSelector").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var myfunc = callBackHandler();

    var urAjax = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: myfunc['url'],
        data: myfunc['data']
    });

    urAjax.always(function(response) {
        $.when( myfunc ).done(function() {
            console.log(myfunc['time']);
            // Handle your ajax response in here!
        });
    });
});

function callBackHandler() {
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    return { url: 'my_ajax_post_url', data: {data1: 'testing', data2: 'testing2'},  time: timestamp }
}
```

fiddle example here:  https://jsfiddle.net/e39oyk8q/15/

Comment: But this will hide the callback for next click event (If it comes in between). .I want to execute the handler when previous one is done irrespective if it comes between or later on

Comment: Have you tried it?  It will run each time after the click is completed.  So each time you click it, it will run after the `callBackHandler` and Ajax functions are completed.  It will save the number of times you clicked it and keep running the clicks for the amount of times you clicked the button.  Example fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/e39oyk8q/7/

Comment: Updated fiddle, not much different, just adds styling really:  https://jsfiddle.net/e39oyk8q/9/

Comment: Hey great help!!! But I am doing some data manipulation in callbackhandler and then sending that to ajax. In your case callbaclHandler will be called after the ajax. But I might be able to tweak from here on. Will let you know. Thanks again :)

Comment: Ok, here's another fiddle that might help you:  https://jsfiddle.net/e39oyk8q/14/  Basically, I am calling the `callBackHandler` function earlier and setting it within a variable called, `myFunc`, than using that variable within the ajax when.  The function gets called before the ajax is finished again.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the binding on the call of function and bind again when the ajax is `done()`.

```
function callBackHandler(){
    $("someSelector").off('click');
    //Some code
    $.ajax({
        //Ajax call with success methods
    }).done(function(){
        $("someSelector").on('click',callBackHandler);
    })
}
```

Comment: in this case my next click event will simply not run. I want to run it but after the execution of previous one

Answer (score 0):

```js
var requestDataButton = document.querySelector('.js-request-data');
var displayDataBox = document.querySelector('.js-display-data');
var displayOperationsBox = document.querySelector('.js-display-operations');
var displayNumberOfRequestsToDo = document.querySelector('.js-display-number-of-requests-to-do');
var isAjaxCallInProgress = false;
var numberOfAjaxRequestsToDo = 0;
var requestUrl = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';

requestDataButton.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick() {
    displayNumberOfRequestsToDo.innerText =  numberOfAjaxRequestsToDo;
  numberOfAjaxRequestsToDo++;
  if(!isAjaxCallInProgress) {
    isAjaxCallInProgress = true;
    requestData();
  }
}

function handleResponse(data) {
  displayData(data);
  displayOperationsBox.innerHTML = displayOperationsBox.innerHTML + 'request handled <br>';
  numberOfAjaxRequestsToDo--;
  displayNumberOfRequestsToDo.innerText =  numberOfAjaxRequestsToDo;
  if(numberOfAjaxRequestsToDo) {
    requestData();
  } else {
    isAjaxCallInProgress = false;
  }
}

function displayData(data) {
  displayDataBox.textContent = displayDataBox.textContent + JSON.stringify(data[0]);
}

function requestData() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', requestUrl, true);

  request.onload = function() {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      handleResponse(data);
    } else {
      // on error
    }
  };

  request.onerror = function() {
    // There was a connection error of some sort
  };

  request.send();
    displayOperationsBox.innerHTML = displayOperationsBox.innerHTML + 'request sent <br>';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="js-request-data">Request Data</button>
<div>
  <h2>Requests wainting in a queue to be sent:
    <span class="js-display-number-of-requests-to-do">
    0
    </span>
  </h2>
  </div>
<div>
  <h2>Operations:</h2>
  <div class="js-display-operations"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Response Data:</h2>
  <div class="js-display-data"></div>
</div>
```

**edit**

here's a utility function that takes similar arguments as $.ajax, and then returns an augmented $.ajax function that keeps an eye on its previous calls and waits for all preceding requests to finish before dispatching another ajax call (are fired sequentially):

```
function sequentialize(requestData, responseHandler) {
  let inProgress = false;
  let deferredRequests = 0;
  const makeRequest = () => {
    $.ajax(requestData).then(processManager);
  };
  const processManager = (data) => {
    responseHandler(data);
    if (deferredRequests) {
      deferredRequests--;
      makeRequest();
    } else {
      inProgress = false;
    }
  };

  return function () {
    if (!inProgress) {
      inProgress = true;
      makeRequest();
    } else {
      deferredRequests++;
    }
  };
}
```